# phpMyAdmin - Invalid authentication method set in configuration: cookie

Tags: phpmyadmin

New install on CentOS 7, latest releases of apache (2.4.20) and php (7.0.6), and latest MariaDB (5.5.47).  I have install this on many servers in the past, reviewed those settings, reviewed the docs, can't seem to figure out what is missing.

Even tried the setup wizard and used that config:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '###.###.###.###';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Also used setting:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

Which works on my other server...???
Same error...

Any suggestions appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll provide a solution, to my own question.

Basically I deleted the install and re installed it from scratch.  Using the exact same config.inc.php previously tested and had returned this error..  So it was not a configuration problem.

Everything now works.

My only guess at this point, is that the error message was bogus, and that some file in the install was either missing or corrupt (I had previously rechecked all permissions..)

Go figure..